# Silverlight 4 RIA Services DDS to ViewModel-AutoComplete Selected Item Binding

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I have an AutoCompleteBox that uses RIA DomainDataSource for the query to the server.  I need to bind the AutoComplete.SelectedItem to the ViewModel.SelectedEmployee.  They share the same DomainContext and data, but have different queries. When I try the following:

ViewModel.SelectedEmployee = autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource;
I get the error:
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to HeadCount.Web.Employee'  ie, it don't work-
I know I could share the queries, but since I have a very large data source this is not possible.
I have managed to display the selected item columns in a datagrid and a button content, but just cannot figure out how to make the app understand it is the same data.  I have been at it for hours, need a little info  Thx

Comment: Well, I read my question an realized that the linr of code should say: ViewModel.SelectedEmployee = autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem;

Comment: And what is the new error message ? The one you quote in the question makes sense for the 'wrong' assignment.

Comment: Timores, thanks for the reply. It was simply a typo in the question, the error message was for:
ViewModel.SelectedEmployee = autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem;

Comment: I found the answer- a missing cast. This line of code made it work-
ViewModel.SelectedEmployee = autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem as HeadCount.Web.Employee;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer- a missing cast. This line of code made it work- ViewModel.SelectedEmployee = autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem as HeadCount.Web.Employee; –